# Weird error while installing Android app?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, failed-installation

In IntelliJ IDEA I exported signed application (created a new key, etc.), entered command `adb install <my_app>.apk` and got an error:

> 1990 KB/s (745096 bytes in 0.365s)
>   pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
>   **Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]**

Google doesn't seem to know about this error. I found the solution where application version in Manifest file was not an integer, but this is not the case with me.

Could I be making a mistake during the creation of new sign key???

EDIT:
Here is my Manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="org.example.app"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0"
        >
    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
        <activity
                android:name=".App"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                        android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category
                        android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
                android:label="@string/about"
                android:name="About"
                ></activity>
        <activity
                android:label="@string/preference"
                android:name="Preference"
                ></activity>
        <activity
                android:name="Empl"
                android:label="@string/empl"
                ></activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?

Comment: What error messages are shown in the device log?

Comment: are you sure your install target is minsdkversion 8 or greater?

Comment: The same message!!! I've created a brand new project, added a simple text box and button and installation went fine from IntelliJ. Only this app is making parse error. Could it be the problem because I started this app in Eclipse and finished it in IntelliJ??

Comment: @nick  I've just seen your reply after I refreshed the page. You were right. Absolutely right! (although I did not see your suggestion, but figured it our myself.)

Comment: @nick: please post a reply and I will mark it as Answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After all it was a mistake in the manifest file. This line made it

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

I tried to deploy Android 2.2 app to a mobile phone with Android 2.1. The other project (the test one) was created in IntelliJ which does not force any version by default.

After I deleted the line or changed version to 7, app installed with no problems.

So rookie mistake :ashamed:.

Comment: I like what you wrote!  Thanks for taking the time to put an answer up to your question.

Comment: thanks, you helped me, too. weird that intelli j doesn't tell you this... eclipse does

Answer (score 7):

Just faced the same error but for other cause -

was trying to move android versionCode to string.xml for easy editing.

WRONG - 
    android:versionCode="@string/version_code">

RIGHT - 
    android:versionCode="101">

Answer (score -1):

Try doing Clean Project from the Build menu and try again.